# Wrong resource url when using URLClassloader to load test classes and run junit tests

Tags: java, junit4, junit5, urlclassloader

I have two maven projects.

**Project 1**: Used to load junit tests classes of project 2 and use junit APIs to programatically execute test cases.

```
String[] classAndMethodNames = ["packageName.Classname","Methodname"];
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder requestBuilder = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request();
requestBuilder.selectors(selectMethod(urlClassLoader.loadClass(classAndMethodNames[0]), classAndMethodNames[1]));
```

**Project 2**:
https://github.com/apache/commons-csv/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/csv/issues/JiraCsv248Test.java

Project 2 loads this class and runs the test org.apache.commons.csv.issues#testJiraCsv248.

**The Problem :**
This test reads a file using a ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(), now the
expected path of this file should be in reference to the Project 2 test class(Project2DIR/filepath), But actually it is Project1/filepath.

Is there any way in which this path can be corrected.

Comment: First of all I would suggest that you don't use hardcoded the systemClassLoader in project 1. Will make it easier for you to switch to a classloader that you can control and where you can provide the tests with the resources they need.

Comment: @cyberbrain you are talking about project 2 right where ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() is used to get the resources, but this project is out of my control. i can make changes in project 1 only. Can you suggest anything there ?

Comment: sorry, I got this mixed up: yes, I'm talking about project 2 where the tests want to read the resource. I'll continue with an answer for the sake of char limits.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should consult the Javadoc of [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()) but in general your approach with the correct URL will not really help you, because a classloader doesn't have to be resolving URLs always.

You could try two approaches:

1. Set the classpath on the execution of project 1 in a way that the test resources of project 1 will be found before anything from project 2
2. Set the system property `java.system.class.loader` to your own implementation of `ClassLoader` that has special handling for the resources for project 1 and delegates anything else to the real system classloader. This is a very hacky solution, so I would prefer #1

For #2, you should set the system property just before you load the first class of project 1, and save the original system classloader before so you can properly delegate all the non-test-resource requests.